# Getting coordinates of polygon areas defined in KML

Tags: google-maps

I have displayed a google map using a KML file as source. The map has a number of polygon areas marked in it. Is there any way to get the center coordinates of each of the polygons without the click event ? I need to display an info window above each polygons when the map is displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[google.maps.KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) is uses tile based rendering, you can't (at least at present) access the coordinates of the polygons except on a click.

You could use:

- [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer), import your KML into that, then query it using either a Fusion Tables API v1.0 or a google.visualization (GViz) query) for the coordinates to get their center.

[example using FusionTablesLayer and GViz](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_Watershed_Stewards_Map_sidebar2.html)

- A third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) to render the polygons as native google.maps.Polygon objects, and get their center.  This will have performance issues with complex KML.

[example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_polygon_highlight.html)